# Is there any way to find text in an _entire_ mongo database?

Tags: mongodb

I have seen plenty of references to doing a "full-text" search in a mongo database, but you always have to specify a collection when doing so.

I'd like to find where a specific string of text is in the database, but I don't know in which collection it resides (and the db I'm using has dozens of collections). Is there any way to search across *all* collections in a database? (Basically the entire database.)

I fully recognize that, if such a capability exists, it would be a super-slow search, but it's just for a one-time search using **NoSQLBooster** to explore the db, so that would be fine.

Comment: You can query the database and get all the collection names as an array. Then loop over the array to query each collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should iterate through collection names (to list collection names use [`listCollections`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.getCollectionNames/#example)), then for each collection, you should create a [Text Index](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-text/#:%7E:text=To%20create%20a%20text%20index%2C%20use%20the%20db.collection.createIndex()) for the `text` field you want to search.
Finally, you can use [`$text` & `$search`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#search-for-a-single-word).

#### PyMongo Example:

Below I've created four collections, each has two documents with fields `_id` & `text`.
One of the documents in each collection has the word **SEARCHINALLCOLL** (e.g. `It's a SEARCHINALLCOLL Sample.`).
I've saved the found results inside a dictionary, sample result is:

```
{'col0': {ObjectId('637fbbda67bb645dc27713eb'): "It's a SEARCHINALLCOLL Sample."}}
```

```py
from pymongo import MongoClient

CONNECTION_STRING = "mongodb://localhost"
MDBClient = MongoClient(CONNECTION_STRING, 27017)

# Create/Access DB
MDB = MDBClient["SEARCHINALLCOLLECTIONS"]

# List all collection names
ListAllColls = MDB.list_collection_names()
# Print all collection names
#print(ListAllColls)
# ['col0', 'col1', 'col3', 'col2']

# Result dictionary {coll_name: {doc_id: doc_text} }
ResultDict = dict()

# Iterate through collections
for coll in ListAllColls:

    # Result dictionary {coll_name} 
    ResultDict[coll] = dict()

    # Create index for <text> field on each document [("field_name", "text")]
    create_text_index = MDB[coll].create_index([("text", "text")])

    # Find ALL documents containing text <SEARCHINALLCOLL> by iterating through each collection
    findtext = MDB[coll].find(
        {
            "$text": {
                "$search": "SEARCHINALLCOLL"
            }
        }
    )
    # Iterate through <findtext> cursor
    for doc in findtext:
        doc_id = doc["_id"]
        doc_text = doc["text"]

        # Store found document's info on dictionary
        # Result dictionary {coll_name: {doc_id: doc_text}} 
        ResultDict[coll][doc_id] = doc_text


# Print saved results dictionary
print(ResultDict)

# Print indexes for collection col0
#print(MDB["col0"].index_information())
```